# Use a class as default database and then customize by inheritance

Tags: python

I have a class default_config which is sort of a default configuration database. To create specific configurations, I overwrite some fields by inheriting `default_config` into a new class and overwrite the field there:

```
class default_config:
    name = ...
    property2 = ...
    property3 = ...
    delta_t = 1
    ...many more properties

cfgs = []

for i in range(10):

    class cfg(default_config):
        delta_t = i

    cfgs.append(cfg)
```

I know that I could also just instantiate a `default_config` and then overwrite `delta_t`.

**But will the presented approach work as expected or are there any caveats?** (Admittedly, the question is of rather academic purpose.)

Comment: 'are there any caveats' is kind of broad, maybe check out [this article](http://pclib.github.io/safari/program/learning-python/Text/ch32s08.html) which covers some common gotchas and unexpected behaviours of class attribute manipulation.

Comment: @stovfl: It does work. `cfgs` is a list of `class cfg(default_config)` with different `delta_t`. I found one problem by myself: Pickling makes troubles, because `cfg` gets overwritten over and over again.